# Automation Anywhere\System file not found in repository in PUBLIC workspace

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I am getting the error message "Automation Anywhere\System file not found in repository in PUBLIC workspace", when i'm trying to start recording.

Please help me....Thank You[image: Please find the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I just had that same problem, Im using the cloud **AA Community Edition on Windows Chrome**.

I really dont know a concrete solution for the problem, but somehow I did the whole setup process again and finally **worked**.

Here I will number the steps I followed, hoping they can help you too.

First of all, make sure you are using **Google Chrome**. I was using Edge at first, then switched to Opera and none of them worked for me.

1. Uninstall everything you have from AA. Also delete the installation files.
2. In the **control room**, remove the device you connected before.
3. Restart the device. (Literally restart your pc)
4. Once restarted log back to the **control room** and begin to add your local device, again (download the `AutomationAnywhereBotAgent`, allow the chrome extension, wait for your device to appear fully connected [connected device sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaQTN.png) ).
5. In the left panel, click on "manage" section, then "devices", in case you were not there already. Click on the 3 dots at the right side of your connected device and select "preload packages". ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4jyp.png))
6. Wait for it to load and just hit "start preloading". ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SywLp.png))
7. Once everything is installed and connected, you should test your bot **before** using the `capture` function. In other words, just run your bot without the problematic function.

**NOTE**: I really recommend to not test the `capture` function yet. **Only** try it after the restart, because I reinstalled and tried the whole set up proccess several times, testing the `capture` function without waiting to restart and the problem persisted.

8. Restart the device. (yes, again)
9. Go back to the **control room**, verify local device status is "connected", test the bot and you should be able to use the `capture` function and continue selecting the window you need without that error.